# Programmatically added button getting crash in storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, storyboard

I am adding a button in `UIScrollView` in `StoryBoard`

Below is the code i am using.

```
-(void)addScrollView
{
    for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        UIScrollView *subScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, SUBSCROLLVIEW_WIDTH, SUBSCROLLVIEW_HEIGHT)];
        UITextView *txtVwDetail = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(342, 0, TEXTVIEW_WIDTH, TEXTVIEW_HEIGHT)];
        txtVwDetail.text = SAMPLE_STRING;
        [self addSubScrollView:subScrollView];
        [self.view addSubview:subScrollView];
        [self.view addSubview:txtVwDetail];
     }
}

-(void)addSubScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aSubScrollView
{
    for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(intBtnX, (aSubScrollView.frame.size.height - 80)/2, 50, 80);
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.items objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        **[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSubImageClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];**    
        aSubScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(intScrollViewWidth, aSubScrollView.frame.size.height);
        [aSubScrollView addSubview:aButton];
    }
}
```

In `addSubScrollView` method I have added Button and its click event which is getting crashed.

```
-(void)btnSubImageClicked
{
    NSLog(@"btnSubImageClicked");
}
```

I am having scenario as

`MyMainViewController` is the `sourceViewController` for my created `customSegue` which is the `UIStoryboardSegue` class

`MyMainViewController` having a UIView as `PlaceHolderView`  in which I am adding `MydestinationViewContoller`'s View which is this Scrollview

```
-(void)perform
{
    BrowseScreenVC *srcObj = (BrowseScreenVC *)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dstObj = (UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    for(UIView *vw in srcObj.viewPlaceHolder.subviews)
    {
        [vw removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSLog(@"dest : %@",dstObj.view);
    NSLog(@"destobj  :%@",dstObj);
    srcObj.currentViewController = dstObj;
    [srcObj.viewPlaceHolder addSubview:[dstObj.view retain]];

}
```

UPDATE

With answer I also have to change the line 
`srcObj.currentViewController = dstObj;`

to

`srcObj.addChildViewController = dstObj;`

to make it working

Comment: What is the error message in your console on crash?

Comment: Are you able to see button in simulator ?

Comment: *** -[MyViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a7f2e0

Comment: what is your "self"? I hope it is viewController.!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add target as follow:

```
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSubImageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

`@selector()`, within these braces you have to provide the method that you want to perform. the ":" represents that the method has some argument. In this case the argument would be the button itself that is calling the method.

You have to implement your method then its signature would look like this

```
- (void)btnSubImageClicked:(id)sender{
// sender would be the button that is calling the method. you can use this object according to your requirements if you want. 

   // your code 
}
```

if you want to call this method from somewhere else as well you can call it by passing sender argument nil. e.g `[self btnSubImageClicked:nil];`

Answer (score 1):

Your action needs to accept an `(id) sender` argument, even if you are not using it:

```
-(void)btnSubImageClicked:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"btnSubImageClicked");
}
```

In the `addSubScrollView`:

```
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSubImageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I have original method with sender but that was getting crashed so for testing purpose I made method without sender.In both case it is getting crashed

Answer (score 1):

Button target should like

```
-(void) btnSubImageClicked:(id)sender{}
```

try this.

Updated:-

Please correct your code,change this line

```
  [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSubImageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Now working i checked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`

write this,

`UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];`

and for better practice always write this,

```
-(void) btnSubImageClicked:(id)sender{}
```